# Elastic Search - store only field

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there an option in elastic search to store vales just for the purpose of retrieving and not used for searching? So when indexing we'll index all fields and when searching we'll search on a single field only, but need other data as well.
For example, we'll index products, fields could be Name, SKU, Supplier Name etc. Out of which, only Name needs to be indexed and searched. SKU and Supplier Name are just for storing and retrieving with a search.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You are first asking for a store only elasticsearch, then you ask for aearch "on a single fields". Decide yourself

Comment: You can use "index":"false" and "store":"true" for a particular field mappings, so that the field will not be searchable as "index":"false" but can be retrived via stored_fields as "store":"true".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `_source` document is stored anyway, the best way to achieve what you want is to neither store nor index any fields, except the one you're searching on, like this:

```
PUT my-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_source": {
      "enabled": true           <--- true by default, but adding for completeness
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "index": true           <--- true by default, but adding for completeness
      },
      "sku": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "index": false,         <--- don't index this field
        "store": false          <--- false by default, but adding for completeness
      },
      "supplier": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "index": false,         <--- don't index this field
        "store": false          <--- false by default, but adding for completeness
      },
    }
  }
}
```

So to sum up:

- the fields you want to search on must have `index: true`
- the fields you don't want to search on must have `index: false`
- `store` is false by default so you don't need to specify it
- `_source` is enabled by default, so you don't need to specify it
- `enabled` should only be used at the top-level or on `object` fields, so it doesn't have its place here

With the above mapping, you can

- search on `name`
- retrieve all fields from the `_source` document since the `_source` field is stored by default and contains the original document

Comment: If we do specify index false and store as true, is there any performance advantage, it would just save on the size of the whole index?

Comment: @ChrisM it means you're not searching on those fields, but still need to retrieve them. Setting index to false means that the documents will ingest more quickly since no analysis takes place (for text fields only). Since the _source is stored in any case (unless disabled), setting store to true would actually increase the required storage since each field would be contained in the _source + stored individually. In the end it depends what kind of fields you have, but it's very easy to test. Create another index with the new mapping with index/store parameters and check the size difference.